# Inner Join to get all attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have 2 tables :

```
albums (idalbum, idauthor, idcompositor, idfeat)
people (id, firstname, last name)
```

My current Query :

```
SELECT * FROM albums where idalbum=:id
INNER JOIN people ON albums.idauthor = people.id
INNER JOIN people ON albums.idcompositor = people.id
INNER JOIN people ON albums.idfeat = people.id
```

What I want to do with my query :

```
[Album], [Author[First Name, Last Name]], [Compositor[First Name, Last Name]], [Feat[First Name, Last Name]]
```

My problem:
I have an error : `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Comment: where is your `auteurs` table ?

Comment: not auteurs, but people sorry

Comment: Most often, it's actually the next bit of the error message that's most useful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to correct your query where clause should be used after your join statements and also you are not using proper table names, according to structure shown in question you can write your query as

```
SELECT * FROM albums  a
INNER JOIN people p ON a.idauthor = p.id
INNER JOIN people p1 ON a.idcompositor = p1.id
INNER JOIN people p2 ON a.idfeat = p2.id
where a.idalbum=:id
```

Comment: the Query works, but when i print_r the result, the last "people" erase the others (i just have 1 name, the name of "p2")

Comment: @CDO this is another question i guess related to php ?

Comment: I got the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23425361/multiple-inner-join-erase-attributes Thanks you for your help :)